# curl to python requests error: "no api key supplied"

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, api-key

I'm trying to do a curl command with python requests. As far as I can tell I'm doing everything correctly but the website won't recognize the api key no matter how I try to include it. Basically, the site I'm trying to reach wants the api key put in the beginning of the url. When I do this with curl, it works perfectly. When I try it via python requests, however, it doesn't work. It also doesn't work to send it in as a key-value pairing in dictionary.

This works

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"ndbno":["11124"],"type":"f"}' [API KEY]@api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports
```

and here's the requests code:

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}

data = '{"ndbno":["11124"],"type":"f"}'

response = requests.post('http://[API KEY]@api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports', headers=headers, data=data)
```

The result from this is a json response containing the message: "{'error': {'code': 'API_KEY_MISSING', 'message': 'No api_key was supplied. Get one at http://api.nal.usda.gov:80'}}
"

It also doesn't work if I remove the [API KEY] from the url and add it to the data dictionary as "api_key":"[API KEY]"

BTW I'm not passing the key in as a list or anything, I just didn't want to post the physical key in my question.

I'm a total newb to python and stackoverflow, but I've done my due diligence and have been searching out answers and testing different ways to format the request for a few hours now. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because requests does not parse the API KEY from the URL, try this:

```
response = requests.post('http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports', headers=headers, data=data, auth=(API_KEY, ''))
```

This passes it using Basic Authentication (`Authorization` header) which is the same behavior that curl does when parsing the URL.

Normally in Basic Auth you would have the username and the password. E.g:
`auth=('<username>', '<password>')`

Since this API only seems to care about the username, I have left the password as blank.

Comment: I tried it just as you suggested but got the exact same error message with my valid api key.

Comment: **UPDATE** Actually I misunderstood the formatting and tried to put the actual key as the second item. When I put my key in as the first item in the auth tuple and left the second blank (as you instructed) it worked like a charm!  Thanks for solving this mystery for me!

I tried to upvote your post but I guess I'm too much of a newb so it won't let me :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PubAG API, it appears that you can simply pass the api_key in the URL query string. I'd assume it's the same for the API you're using, but a cursory search yielded no documentation.

Try:
https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports?api_key=[API_KEY]

```
response = requests.post('https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports?api_key=[API_KEY]', headers=headers, data=data)
```

I don't have an API key to try this out with, but navigating to https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports?api_key=asdfds in my browser gives me an invalid API key error, which suggests that the endpoint recognizes that I've given an API key.